# GCC emits extra code for boost::shared_ptr dereference

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, boost, assembly

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct Foo { int a; };
static int A;

void
func_shared(const boost::shared_ptr<Foo> &foo) {
    A = foo->a;
}

void
func_raw(Foo * const foo) {
    A = foo->a;
}
```

I thought the compiler would create identical code, but for `shared_ptr` version an extra seemingly redundant instruction is emitted.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <func_raw(Foo*)>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
   6:   5d                      pop    ebp
   7:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   9:   a3 00 00 00 00          mov    ds:0x0,eax
   e:   c3                      ret
   f:   90                      nop

00000010 <func_shared(boost::shared_ptr<Foo> const&)>:
  10:   55                      push   ebp
  11:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  13:   8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
  16:   5d                      pop    ebp
  17:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
  19:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
  1b:   a3 00 00 00 00          mov    ds:0x0,eax
  20:   c3                      ret
```

I'm just curious, is this necessary, or it is just an optimizer's shortcoming?

Compiling with `g++ 4.1.2`, `-O3 -NDEBUG`.

Comment: What happens if you pass the `shared_ptr` by value instead of by reference? Or conversely, what happens if you pass the `Foo*` by reference?

Comment: @greyfade, Curiously, the code emitted for the function is exactly the same, but at the call site the ref. count is being changed due to copying when passing by value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a 'redundant' instruction.

The relevant section of the first code snippet is equivalent to:
*p

Whilst in the second it's equivalent to:
**p

Due to shared_ptr's internals there is a second level of indirection. This is not something the optimizer can 'fix'.

At any rate, the difference is negligible.

EDIT:

Whoops! My apologies, I misread your code.

You are passing the shared_ptr BY REFERENCE in your code. That will pass it "by pointer" at the ASM level.

So you're passing a pointer to a shared_ptr, and that shared_ptr contains a pointer to your object.

Hence the two levels of indirection.

Sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that boost's implementation actually contains object's pointer directly in its body, so the second level of indirection is only used when incrementing/decrementing reference count (accessing shared ref.counter structure). Accessing a pointer should only be a single indirection.

Comment: You are correct, I misread.

The second level of indirection is caused by the shared_ptr being passed by reference.

Comment: Yes, that, indeed, seems to be the case!